# How to create editable password policy using Flask?

Tags: python-3.x, django, flask-sqlalchemy, password-policy

I want to create an editable password policy using Flask. Admin can tick the any password policy in the menu (Please see admin menu page image).

[image: Admin menu page]

Based on the selection password policy need to be updated.

How can I Implement it??

Comment: Store those preferences in your database (maybe a generic settings table), then read them when you're validating passwords?

Comment: How to store the policies in the database.? Is it in the form of regular expression?

Comment: You don't need to store a regexp in the database. Just store e.g. `require_password_upper_lower_case = True` or whatnot, and check for the existence of that in your password validator.

Comment: Thank You Mr.AKX. I will try that.

Comment: Thank you. That worked